# Automation Testing Data Driven with Ranorex, Next Case When Validate Return False.

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, data-driven-tests, ranorex

1)When I use feature "manage datasource" of Ranorex to data driven. If all case true, program will return success. But if i have a false case, it will stop program immediately and return error Validation failed.
Ex : I have 3 case, case 1 is false. Output will be 1x Failed and 2x Blocked.
So, I want to run all case including false case. Output will not be any case blocked. 
I tried using check variable to call Validate.Fail() but still not be. And i don't want to use normal connections by C# to Excel.

```
void ITestModule.Run(){
Host.Local.RunApplication("C:\\Users\\FSU1.TEST\\Downloads\\Calculator.exe", "", "C:\\Users\\FSU1.TEST\\Downloads", false);

        //run test Calculator
        Button btnX = "/form[@controlname='Calculator']/button[@controlname='Button"+_btn1+"']";
        btnX.Click();
        MyRepo.Calculator.ButtonTimes.Click();
        Button btnY = "/form[@controlname='Calculator']/button[@controlname='Button"+_btn2+"']";
        btnY.Click();
        MyRepo.Calculator.ButtonEqual.Click();

        //set result
        Text text = "/form[@controlname='Calculator']/?/?/text[@accessiblerole='Text']";

        //Validate result
        Validate.AreEqual(text.TextValue, value, "True");

        MyRepo.Calculator.ButtonClear.Click();
        MyRepo.Calculator.Close.Click();
}
```

And here is data binding
[data binding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRpMh.png)

And another problem:
2)In which I have a column "result" to write result test. Can I use binding to write it ?

Thanks
Sargon

Comment: May I ask why doing all the recording in user code?  I recommend using user code to do flow execution control (decisions) only.  When sequence is linear, it is preferable to use simple recording.  Your tests will be much easier to maintain in the end.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, your problem relies on the fact the `Validate.AreEqual` throws an exception and stops the test execution (thus blocking next iterations).

For your test to continue running after the first failure, configure the **Error Behavior** of the test case in the test suite to **Continue with iteration** upon error.

This will not fix the fact that the cleanup is still done after the validation (not executed when test fails).  You need to create another recording which will do the cleanup (button clear, app close actions).  You add this new recording after the first one in a **Teardown** section of the test case.  This will ensure that cleanup is executed regardless of the test result.

Hope this sends you in the right direction.

I would finally recommend starting the app in another recording which is executed before the test and placed in a **Setup** section.

For more information on how Ranorex test suite works, see the following article:
[Lesson 4 Ranorex Test Suite](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-4-ranorex-test-suite.html)